# Amazon MWS - SubmitFeed is sent successfully, but won't be processed

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws

I'm trying to write a program that will automatically create and update a list of products on Amazon. So what I'm doing is sending an XML File via the SubmitFeed function, provided in the SDK. When running the program, I'm getting the following response:

> FeedType
>   _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_
>
> SubmittedDate
>   2014-01-09T13:56:00Z
>
> FeedProcessingStatus
>   _ SUBMITTED _

When asking for the result of my request with GetFeedSubmissionResult, it returns that the submission was "successful". Still, the update doesn't happen. Amazon Support and forum aren't able (or willing?) to help me with that problem.

This is the code I'm using (for testing issues, I'm just trying to change the title of a single product):

```
include_once ('.config.inc.php');

$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.de";

$config = array (
  'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
  'ProxyHost' => null,
  'ProxyPort' => -1,
  'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);

 $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
     $config,
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     APPLICATION_VERSION);

$haendler_token = '##TOKEN##';

$feed = '';
$feed.= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$feed.= '<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
$feed.= '   <Header>';
$feed.= '       <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>';
$feed.= '       <MerchantIdentifier>'.$haendler_token.'</MerchantIdentifier>';
$feed.= '   </Header>';
$feed.= '   <MessageType>Product</MessageType>';
$feed.= '   <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>';
$feed.= '    <Message>';
$feed.= '        <MessageID>1</MessageID>';
$feed.= '        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>';
$feed.= '        <Product>';
$feed.= '           <SKU>##SKU##</SKU>';
$feed.= '           <DescriptionData>';
$feed.= '               <Title>##TITLE##</Title>';
$feed.= '           </DescriptionData>';
$feed.= '       </Product>';
$feed.= '    </Message>';
$feed.= '</AmazonEnvelope>';

$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array('A1PA6795UKMFR9'));
$feedHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
rewind($feedHandle);
$parameters = array (
  'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
  'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
  'FeedType' => '_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_',
  'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
  'PurgeAndReplace' => false,
  'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true)),
);
rewind($feedHandle);
$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
invokeSubmitFeed($service,$request);
@fclose($feedHandle);
```

I'm being pretty desperate about the whole thing. Thanks to anyone reading this!

Answer (score 0):

There is a system called detail page control that decides what content appears on the public product detail pages. It might accept your title for the detail page or it might not. http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200202130

If the title was submitted properly, you should be able to find it in Seller Central if you try to manually edit the product detail page (instructions on that here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_sib?ie=UTF8&nodeId=200202090)

Comment: When I'm the only one providing a certain product, the changes should always show up, shouldn't they?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. If you need the title changed and the changes weren't accepted then you can open a ticket with Seller Support to ask them about it.